# Bioenergetics book, biophysics

Tags: resource-recommendations, biophysics

In the field of biophysics, it seems there is a subfield called "bioenergetics" about the processes of generating energy by biology.
I am looking for a book to be introduced to the physics aspects of bioenergetics.
I checked up on Springer and there seem to be quite some books on the topic, but the problem is that I fear that they would require heavy biology basics.

Comment: I feel like that is such a broad topic that you pretty much need the biology basics. The many of the players involved in biological energy are basic biological elements you will need to understand.

Comment: @AaronStevens I posted it there aswell.

Comment: I wasn't saying anything about where this should be posted. I was addressing your concern about resources requiring heavy biology basics. I'm saying I don't think you can get around knowing the biology basics here.

Comment: Well as long as the book is self-contained, I am fine with it; just saying that I am looking for a book more based on the physics less than the biology aspects.

Comment: Although it doesn't address "bioenergetics", you might consider starting with [Biophysics Demystified](https://www.amazon.com/Biophysics-DeMYSTiFied-Daniel-Goldfarb/dp/0071633642/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=biophysics+demystified&qid=1568680094&sr=8-1)  It is based more on physics than biology, has a chapter on "Energy and Life", and gives a good overview of biology for people who have taken some chemistry or physics.

Comment: @GregThatcher That was what I was looking for!